# Exract a id from git show using power shell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have the below input from a GIT show:

```
commit d5089c3135e104c2b508fe58d98596c96b2ae19a Merge: bd82ec4 d36607b Author:  Thomas <thomas@gmail> Date:   Fri Feb 7 18:48:38 2020 +0000      Merged in test_cicd (pull request #93)          PIS-504     id="VN.P.1.0.1"
```

I need to parse the id and then save to the variable  .
EX : VN.P.1.0.1

Mycode is

```
$build = git  show
$id = if ($build -match '\bid=("\d"+)\b') { $Matches[1] }
```

but not working..help anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you find the `id`enclosed in double-quotes, get everything *not* a double quote:

```
$id = if ($build -match '\bid="([^"]+)"') { $Matches[1] }
# this                          ^^^^^
```

**Update**: based on comments, guessing the actual `git` output is different than what's displayed in the OP's example. Replaced with `\s` whitespace character [word boundary metacharacter](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:46
+ $id = if ($build -match '\s+id="([^"]+)"') { $Matches[1] }
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 

showing above error

Comment: Answer $build -match '\s+id="([^"]+)"'|%{$_.split('"')[1]}
matches array is empty

Comment: @arunthomas - verify `$build` is not empty. `Write-Host $build`

Comment: @ kuujinbo build is not empty but still got same error

Comment: @ kuujinbo 
is it possible to convert the  value to lower ?